# ls |head (offset?)

Tags: linux, ls, tail, head

Is there a way to paginate the `ls` command? For example, to get the first 50 items I can do:

```
$ ls -U |head -50
```

How would I then do:

```
$ ls -U | head -50 "offset 50"
```

Or, does this require to pipe it through a second command, such as:

```
$ ls -U  | tail -n +50 |head -n 50
```

Comment: `ls -U | less  --LINE-NUMBERS`, how about the line number

Comment: This might help [How to activate pagination for ls command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19718/how-to-activate-pagination-for-ls-command)

Comment: Is the output that you want for looking at, or looping over?

Comment: @Kusalananda just for looking at/printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is not a standard. If you want to scroll up and down in a file, pipe the output though less.

Example:

```
ls | less
```